# Understanding the role of domain in the question related to Cauchy theorem for complex integral

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

**Cauchy theorem**: If a function $f$ is analytic on a simply connected domain $D$ and $C$ is a simple closed contour lying in $D$ then
$ \int _{\gamma} f(z)dz=0 $.

**My doubt** Cauchy's theorem states that a function $f$ must be analytic in a domain $D$ and $\gamma$ is a closed contour within $D$. However, I often encounter questions that mention $\gamma$ but doesn't specify the domain $D$. Many questions do not explicitly mention the domain, but assumption is typically that you should chhose an appropriate $D$ to make theorem applicable.

For example using this theorem $ \int _{\gamma} \frac{1}{z^2}dz=0 $, where ${\gamma}$ is $(x-2)^2 + \frac{1}{4}(y - 5)^2 = 1$. My confusion is what domain $D$ should I consider where I can see $\gamma$ is a closed contour. Should I take arbitrary domain containing $\gamma$?

Kindly help me to clear this doubt.

Comment: Your statement of Cauchy's Theorem on line 1 is false.  What text did you get this from?

Comment: @user8675309  Could you please guide me whats wrong in the statement? Thanks

Comment: the punctured plane $\mathbb C -\big\{0\big\}$ is a domain $D$ and $f$ given by $f(z) =\frac{1}{z}$ is holomorphic on it and this leads to many integrals contradicting your statement (e.g. $\gamma$ being the standard path around the unit circle).  Again I ask where you got this "theorem" from.

Comment: @user8675309 Thanks for your comment. I wish you could have elaborated and given me proper answer. I am not able to find mistakes and neither you are writing what is the right statement for cauchys theorem.

Comment: @user8675309 Here is the links https://www.iitg.ac.in/jitumath/Lecture%209.pdf

Comment: @user8675309 Did you mean domain D should be simply connected? Kindly explain

Comment: You wrote "I am not able to find mistakes and neither you are writing what is the right statement for cauchys theorem" yet a correct form of Cauchy Goursat is given on page 3 of your link. Being simply connected is a big deal. It is incumbent on you the OP to accurately state the theorem you are asking about-- e.g. there is a minimum amount of work expected of original posters *and there are multiple forms of Cauchy Goursat and we shouldn't be guessing which one you are trying to use.* Providing a citation for your theorem is a partial workaround which is why I asked you multiple times for it.

Comment: I don’t understand the need for the bounty here. What you wrote is wrong, and the link has a correct version of the theorem. What more are you looking for in an answer?

Comment: Also, in concrete questions, you can immediately see where the function is holomorphic, for example, $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2}$ is holomorphic in $D=\Bbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ (and it also has a primitive there, so by the fundamental theorem of calculus, regardless of the fact that $D$ is not simply connected, for every closed loop $\gamma$, we have $\int_{\gamma}\frac{dz}{z^2}=0$).

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thank you so much. Shall I delete this question?

Comment: up to you, or you can just answer your own question.